# ActionBar appcompat submenu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, submenu, android-appcompat

In my application android I would like to add an actionbar like this (that it have a submenu)

[image]

my xml code is

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
        android:title="Search Products">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_Home"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Home"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_favourite"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="favourite"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_Balance"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Balance"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="Logout"/>
</menu>
```

in android sdk 2.x the result it's not what i want

[image]

i tryed also

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/root_menu"
    DetailsPage:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light"
    android:title="More">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_Home"
            DetailsPage:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
            android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
            android:title="Home"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_Balance"
            DetailsPage:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
            android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
            android:title="Balance"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_logout"
            android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
            DetailsPage:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
            android:title="Logout"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

what I what to do to have the same picture plz ( maybe menu popup ?)

help me plz

Answer (score 3):

Changing the namespace from app to compat solved my problem:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >


    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_submenu"
        android:title="@string/action_submenu"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_dark"
        compat:showAsAction="always">

        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_settings"
                android:title="@string/action_settings"
                compat:showAsAction="always"/>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_example"
                android:title="@string/action_example"
                compat:showAsAction="withText|ifRoom"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Comment: WTH? Of all the solutions out there, this is the only one that has worked for me! Wow and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your using the namespaces in the wrong way. To have the showAsAction property to work properly you have to use the "app" namespace not the android one. In your first try you're using it and every time you set `showAsAction="never"`. That's why you're not getting the expected result.

Remove all your `android:showAsAction="..."` and set all the `app:showAsAction="always"` or `="ifRoom|withText"`

Hope I answered your question, if I did please check it as right answer.